# Vora Spark shell syntax

Tags: vora

Are there any programmatic differences in the Spark shell used for Vora over the Scala Spark syntax. I need to make sure I can use the widely available Spark examples. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The Spark shell is the same, using it with Vora means defining a new SAP sql context that adds to Spark sql context new functionality.

So you can still use it for running Spark sql scenarios that do not necessarily involve Vora.